# Is there a residually finite group not finitely presented?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, group-presentation

I am looking for a residually finite group which is not finitely presented. Does such a group exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found a nice example: the lamplighter group $L_2= \mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}$. There is a natural morphism from $L_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}_n$ and a such morphism, for $n$ big enough, send a non-trivial element on a non-trivial element in the finite group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \wr \mathbb{Z}_n$.

Moreover, one can show that $F \wr \mathbb{Z}$ is residually finite iff $F$ is abelian.

Comment: Would it be okay for you to give a reference that $F \wr \mathbb{Z}$ is residually finite iff $F$ is abelian?

Answer (score 3):

$G =\displaystyle\prod_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not finitely generated (hence not finitely presented) whenever $I$ is infinite. Using projection homomorphisms you can show $G$ to be residually finite.

I can't think of an easy answer for finitely generated groups, but a look at the result in this [paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fbull%2F1969-75-02%2FS0002-9904-1969-12149-X%2FS0002-9904-1969-12149-X.pdf&ei=Duf7T5KeHcSjrQGyotGLCQ&usg=AFQjCNHpFl3Mbdnib_4DtwZJFsq385phng) towards the bottom of page 4 shows that that the [Lamplighter Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamplighter_group) should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A more interesting example would be a finitely generated group.

Comment: Looks like you got there before me.